# How can I change code inside a <pre></pre> and change it into a table without losing empty lines?

Tags: c#, html-table

I have been using some code that takes as input HTML and then changes 
code inside a `<pre> ... </pre>` and makes it into a table. Here's the 
code:

```
    public static string FormatCode(this string content)
    {
        var data1 = content
            .Split(new[] { "<pre>", "</pre>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var data2 = data1
            .Select((s, index) =>
            {
                string s1 = index % 2 == 1 ? string.Format("{0}{2}{1}",
                    "<table class='code'>", "</table>", SplitJoin(s)) : s;
                return s1;
            });
        var data3 = data2.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
        var data4 = string.Join("\n", data3);
        return data4;
    }

    private static string SplitJoin(string content)
    {
        IEnumerable<String> code =
            content.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select((line, index) =>
                    string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td><pre><code>{1}</code></pre></td></tr>\n",
                    (index + 1).ToString("D2"), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(line)));
        return string.Join("", code) + "\n";
    }
```

If my HTML is like this:

```
<p>xxx</p><pre>public enum XXX {
   private String command1;

   private String command2;
   }
}</pre>
```

It converts this into:

```
<table class="code"><tbody>
<tr><td>01</td><td><p>xxx</p></td></tr>
<tr><td>02</td><td><pre>public enum XXX {</pre></td></tr>
<tr><td>03</td><td><pre>   private String command1;</pre></td></tr>
<tr><td>04</td><td><pre>   private String command2;</pre></td></tr>
<tr><td>05</td><td><pre>}</pre></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The problem is that empty line inside a `<pre>` are not output. Can someone help me
by telling me how I could change my code so that when there is an empty line in the
`<pre>` then it still outputs a row with a correct row number and something with an `&nbsp;`

Update:  Following a suggested answer I tried making a change to my function to this:

```
    IEnumerable<String> code =
        // content.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        content.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select((line, index) =>
                string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td><pre><code>{1}</code></pre></td></tr>\n",
                (index + 1).ToString("D2"), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(line)));
    return string.Join("", code) + "\n";
```

However I still do not see the empty lines in the tables.

Comment: Why do you need a table?

Comment: You did not show the code that actually do the work (`SplitJoin`), so either post it or close the question. Side note: consider HtmlAgilityPack to extract HTML content - much safer and easier to use compared to issues with searching for begin/end tags...

Comment: your current output doesn't seem quite right. What happened  to <p>xxx</p> ?

Comment: knittl - Using a table allows a really nice formatted view of the code. It looks very good except for the problem with the empty lines that do not show up. @Alexei - I added the code. I am sorry for not including this. Mr.Mindor - Thanks for pointing this out. The actual input and output were much larger and I tried here to cut them down in size. Unfortunately I missed out the first line when doing this.

Answer (score 1):

[`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) removes empty entries when splitting on the newline character. If you don't want to remove empty entries, don't use this option.

Comment: I changed the line you mentioned to: content.Split(new[] { '\n' })  but it still does not show the empty lines. It looked like there's an option .None so I tried that "content.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.None)" Still it does not give the empty lines.

Comment: Did you recompile before running your program again?

Comment: Yes I did. I am using C# and I have to stop, compile and restart before my program will run.